# 'Identifier expected' error when making int enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to make an enum of integers, but it's giving me this error: 'Identifier expected'.

`enum chars : int { 192, 193 };`

Comment: You can't start a name with a digit.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A number is not a valid identifier (name) for a enum value. You need to define it like:

```
enum chars : int { first = 192, second = 193 }
```

Comment: It's a shame you cant have an enum `enum chars : int { 192 = 193, 193 = 192 }` etc.

Comment: But you could solve it like: `enum chars : int { _192 = 193, _193 = 192 }` ;-) @EdPlunkett

Comment: Correction: A number is not a valid identifier (name) for **any c# type**

Comment: Good enough -- you can't let the perfect be the enemy of the awful :)

Comment: Also, why explicitly say that the enum is of int type? That's the default

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto in terms of code readability this is not a bad idea (of course no must). Same question could be why add `private` explicit to fields - because of readability!